# Creating an animation from multiple data files

Tags: gnuplot

I have some C++ code that generates data I want to create an animated gif (or equivalent) from. The data is output into .txt files with the names 1, 2, 3, 4 ..., N with 2 columns (x y data points). For simplicity say we use 100 files.

There seems to be 1 of 2 ways to do this, either create 100 png images from the 100 files then use GIMP to create a gif or create a gif automatically via GNUplot. The first I should be able to do with a loop, say;

`set term png
for [i=1:100] {set output "data".i."png"; plot 'filepath/'.i.'.txt' with lines title ""; set output}`

Which gives me the error: 'invalid complex constant'. This I suspect is just be being bad with GNUplot syntax.

As for the second, the examples I can find make it unclear how to use data to generate the plots.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: EDIT: The loop wont work because I have GNUplot 4.4 and that style of loop is not supported. Is there a way to do what I am trying with the

<code>plot for [i=1:100] '/fileplath/'.i ?

Answer (score 1):

For gnuplot versions older than 4.6 you can use `reread` to do such kind of looping.

Consider the file `looper.gp`:

```
set output 'data'.i.'.png'
plot 'filepath/'.i.'.txt' with lines notitle
i = i + 1
if (i <= 100) reread
```

Call this with

```
i = 1
set terminal png
load 'looper.gp'
set output
```